# Test if a function runs in the past minute or second javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm using socket.io with a node.js server in communication between clients, and in receiving message from one client I do some treatment in the callback and i have some code that run every time and some that must run once a minute to store data in a mysql database:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
       socket.on('createroom', function(room) {
                socket.on('values', function(values) {
                        treatment done each time with values;
                        treatment must be done once a minute with values;
                }
       }
}
```

How I can test if a function or some code has run in the past minute.

Comment: Is it once per minute per client or once per minute for all clients?

Comment: It is once per minute per client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can record as a socket property, when you last processed this event and just check that time:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    // initialize lastProcessed time to a long time ago (haven't done it yet)
    socket.lastProcessed = 0;
    socket.on('createroom', function(room) {
        // there's a problem here because you will create duplicate event handlers
        // for the values message
        socket.on('values', function(values) {
            treatment done each time with values;
            if (Date.now() - socket.lastProcessed > (1000 * 60)) {
                treatment must be done once a minute with values;
                // update time we last processed it
                socket.lastProcessed = Date.now();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

FYI, you have another problem here that every time you get the `createroom` event you are adding another listener for the `values` message.  You will end up with duplicate handlers for that message which is a problem.  Since you don't explain the overall logic here, I'm not quite sure what solution to that would be best.

Possible solutions.  Assign the `values` event handler at the same scope as you assign the `createroom` event handler or remove the `values` event handler after it occurs.

Comment: I do not understand about duplicate handlers.

Comment: @omarbouzoumita - Every time the `createroom` message is received on a given socket, you add a new handler for the `values` message for that socket.  So, if you receive the `createroom` message three times on one socket, you will have three handlers for the `values` message on that socket and when the `values` message is received, you will execute the handler for that message three times.

Comment: just i want to say the condition must be the contraire Date.now() - socket.lastProcessed > (1000 * 60)